# BlackBerry Persistent store

Tags: blackberry, persistence

I am developing an application in which I want to store many data entries using persistent store. the problem is whenever new entry is made it replaces the existing entry.
here is my code please help me.

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.util.*;
import java.util.*;
/*An application in which user enters the data. this data is displayed when user press the save button*/
public class Display extends UiApplication {
/*declaring Strings to store the data of the user*/
 String getFirstName;
 String getLastName;
 String getEmail;
 String getGender;
 String getStatus;
 /*declaring text fields for user input*/
 private AutoTextEditField firstName;

 private AutoTextEditField lastName;

 private EmailAddressEditField email;
/*declaring choice field for user input*/
 private ObjectChoiceField gender;
 /*declaring check box field for user input*/
 private CheckboxField status;
 //Declaring button fields
 private ButtonField save;
 private ButtonField close;

 /*declaring vector*/
 private static Vector _data;
 /*declaring persistent object*/
 private static PersistentObject store;

 /*creating an entry point*/
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 /*creating instance of the class */
 Display app = new Display();
 app.enterEventDispatcher();
}

/*creating default constructor*/
 public Display() 
 {
  /*Creating an object of the main screen class to use its functionalities*/
  MainScreen mainScreen = new MainScreen();

  //setting title of the main screen
  mainScreen.setTitle(new LabelField("Enter Your Data"));

  //creating text fields for user input
  firstName = new AutoTextEditField("First Name: ", "");
  lastName= new AutoTextEditField("Last Name: ", "");
  email= new EmailAddressEditField("Email:: ", "");

  //creating choice field for user input
  String [] items = {"Male","Female"};
  gender= new ObjectChoiceField("Gender",items);
  //creating Check box field
  status = new CheckboxField("Active",true);
  //creating Button fields and adding functionality using listeners
  save = new ButtonField("Save",ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
  save.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener()
  {
   public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
   {
    save();
   }
  });
  close = new ButtonField("Close",ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
  close.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener()
  {
   public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
   {
    onClose();
   }
  });
  //adding the input fields to the main screen
  mainScreen.add(firstName);
  mainScreen.add(lastName);
  mainScreen.add(email);
  mainScreen.add(gender);
  mainScreen.add(status);
  //adding buttons to the main screen
  mainScreen.add(close);
  mainScreen.add(save);

  //adding menu items

  mainScreen.addMenuItem(saveItem);
  mainScreen.addMenuItem(getItem);
  //pushing the main screen
  pushScreen(mainScreen);
 }
//adding functionality to menu item "saveItem" 
private MenuItem saveItem = new MenuItem("Save", 110, 10) 
{
  public void run() 
  {
   //Calling save method
   save();
  }
};
//adding functionality to menu item "saveItem" 
private MenuItem getItem = new MenuItem("Get", 110, 11) 
{
 //running thread for this menu item
 public void run() 
 {
  //synchronizing thread
  synchronized (store) 
  {
   //getting contents of the persistent object
   _data = (Vector) store.getContents();
   //checking for empty object
   if (!_data.isEmpty()) 
   {
    //if not empty
    //create a new object of Store Info class
    StoreInfo info = (StoreInfo)
    //returning last component of the vector
    _data.lastElement();
    //storing information retrieved in strings
    getFirstName = (info.getElement(StoreInfo.NAME));
    getLastName  = (info.getElement(StoreInfo.LastNAME));
    getEmail   = (info.getElement(StoreInfo.EMail));
    getGender   =  (info.getElement(StoreInfo.GenDer));
    getStatus  = (info.getElement(StoreInfo.setStatus));

    //calling the show method
    show();
   }
  }
 }
};
//coding for persistent store
static {
store =
PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(0xdec6a67096f833cL);
synchronized (store) {
if (store.getContents() == null) {
store.setContents(new Vector());
store.commit();
}
}
_data = new Vector();
_data = (Vector) store.getContents();

}
//new class store info implementing persistable
private static final class StoreInfo implements Persistable 
{
 //declaring variables
 private Vector _elements;
 public static final int NAME = 0;
 public static final int LastNAME = 1;
 public static final int EMail= 2;
 public static final int GenDer = 3;
 public static final int setStatus = 4;

 public StoreInfo() 
 {
  _elements = new Vector(5);
  for (int i = 0; i < _elements.capacity(); ++i) 
  {
   _elements.addElement(new String(""));
  }
 }

 public String getElement(int id) 
 {
  return (String) _elements.elementAt(id);
 }
 public void setElement(int id, String value) 
 {
  _elements.setElementAt(value, id);
 }
}
//details for show method
public void show()
{
 Dialog.alert("Name is "+getFirstName+" "+getLastName+"\nGender is "+getGender+"\nE-mail: "+getEmail+"\nStatus is "+getStatus);
}
//creating save method
public void save()
{
 //creating an object of inner class StoreInfo
 StoreInfo info = new StoreInfo();
 //getting the test entered in the input fields
 info.setElement(StoreInfo.NAME, firstName.getText());
 info.setElement(StoreInfo.LastNAME,lastName.getText());
 info.setElement(StoreInfo.EMail, email.getText());
 info.setElement(StoreInfo.GenDer,gender.toString());
 if(status.getChecked())
  info.setElement(StoreInfo.setStatus, "Active");
 else
  info.setElement(StoreInfo.setStatus, "In Active");
 //adding the object to the end of the vector
 _data.addElement(info);
 //synchronizing the thread
 synchronized (store) 
 {

  store.setContents(_data);
  store.commit();
 }
 //resetting the input fields

 Dialog.inform("Success!");
 firstName.setText(null);
 lastName.setText(null);
 email.setText("");
 gender.setSelectedIndex("Male");
 status.setChecked(true);
}
//overriding onClose method
public boolean onClose()
{
 System.exit(0);
 return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you its all working now. i owe u man. i owe u big.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually it's saves everything perfectly, but retrieving only the last one record:

```
StoreInfo info = (StoreInfo)_data.lastElement();
```

Try this to display every record:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _data.size(); i++) {
StoreInfo info = (StoreInfo)_data.elementAt(i);
...
show();
}
```